# Motor without magnetism

Tags: motor, magnetics, electron

Every electric motor I know, takes electricity and converts it over a magnetic field, for generating movement.

Is it possible to generate significant movement, based only only on electrons movement?

Comment: How do your muscles work?

Comment: wasn't this recently asked?  and the answer was down to the force generated by an electrical field as oppose to a magnetic field

Comment: There are also electrostatic motors.

Comment: Piezoelectric motors too.  They are often used for small high resolution movements.

Comment: In principle, you could use bimetallic strips and heat them up resistively to make some type of actuator.

Comment: A piezoelectric motor is just a form of electrostatic motor.  One could also, in theory, have a motor driven by some sort of electro-chemical reaction.

Comment: @mkeith - In fact, there are micro-actuators based on the bimetallic scheme.

Comment: The movement of electrons is basically the flow of current and any flow of current generates a magnetic field. This makes your question difficult to understand.

Comment: @JonRB: asked where?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, one for example is the [electrostatic motor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatic_motor) which uses only charge to create motion. No magnetic field required.